# JLO Rockwell 2F600

Tags: oil-change, gasoline, two-stroke, air-fuel-ratio

I have an old hovercraft that uses a small aircraft engine in the front to power both the lift and forward propulsion. I was hoping to find any kind of manual or literature on the engine itself. The hovercraft is an Aircycle 410, built in the early 70s. The engine is a two stroke with horizontally opposed cylinders. I am able to get the engine to turn over with a car battery, but I want a little more info on how to apply either oil, gas, or an oil/gas mixture in order to power the machine before I start making random guesses and destroy the thing in the process.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [maintenance manual](http://www.vintagesnow.com/Engine_manuals_files/2F-440-3_SM.pdf) for another JLO 2-cyl 2-stroke engine. While it isn't exactly the same, I would bet the maintenance would be the same between the models.

As an aside, since the motor is air cooled, ensure the fans and shrouding are in place on motor before you try to start it.

Doing some searching, your engine (and variants) were used *extensively* in snow machines for the late 60's, early 70's. There seems to be parts/motors available for replacement, at least.